# Animating a calendar rip and tear

Tags: animation

I've been trying to animate a calendar for christmas, similar to this one: https://www.instagram.com/p/C0KuUpVuir2/?hl=pt-br

[image]

How can I do the calendar ripping animation? Would love some resources or video tutorials to learn this technique.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a curve that is aligned with the X axis and looks like that, then in *Object* mode rotate it a bit on Z:

[image]

Then keyframe its movement on X so that it makes the sheet fly away:

[image]

As for the ripping effect on the paper you can create a b&w mask with transparency:

[image]

File: [image]

Comment: Wowwwww! That is such a clever idea! Would you mind sharing the project file?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://blend-exchange.com/b/rWA8j61Q